# Django file download pass value from template view

Tags: python, django

I have a template view in django, On that template i have a download button:

```
<a href="{% url 'smarts_cfg:template-download' cfg_template.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Download file</a>
```

URL:

```
path('<int:pk>/edit/download/', smarts_cfg_views.CgfFileDownload.as_view(), name='template-download'),
```

View:

```
class CgfFileDownload(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        content = MODEL_NAME.objects.get(pk=pk).name
        response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'testing.txt'
        return response
```

It works as intended. What i want to do is before pressing the button and downloading the file, i want user to fill a field on the template and i want to pass this information to the download view (without saving it in the database). What is the best way to do it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `a` tag with `button`.
Wrap a `form` tag over the button and add `type=submit` to  it.
In the `form`, you can add the `input` field.

**Template**:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'smarts_cfg:template-download' cfg_template.pk %}">
    <!-- your input field -->
    <input type="text" name="fieldName" />

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Download file</button>
</form>
```

**View**:

```
class CgfFileDownload(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        # query parameters are stored in `request.GET` dictionary
        fieldValue = request.GET.get('fieldName')

        content = MODEL_NAME.objects.get(pk=pk).name
        response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'testing.txt'
        return response
```

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what i was looking for!